# Integal measure

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In this post [How can I understand the tunneling problem by Euclidean path integral where the quadratic fluctuation has a negative eigenvalue?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219056/how-can-i-understand-the-tunneling-problem-by-euclidean-path-integral-where-the)  we have
path integration variable $x$ is expanded around the $\bar{x}$ 
$\tag{2.5} x(t^E)~=~\bar{x}(t^E) + y(t^E), \qquad  y(t^E)~:=~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x_n(t^E),$

The integral measure is then  defined as $\tag{2.7} [dx]~=~\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{dc_n}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}.$

Should it not be

$[dx(t^E)]=[dy(t^E)]$

Why can we define the integral measure? Are the $c_n$ not constant or am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - what do you mean by "why"? It's a *definition*, we don't need a reason to be allowed to make definitions. What exactly do you want to know about that step?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315427/2451