# Vacuum Stability

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vacuum, quantum-tunneling, instantons

I am studying one of the paper of Sidney Coleman, "Fate of the False Vacuum. II. First quantum corrections". Just before eq. (2.18) he says

> "Because of time translation invariance, this equation necessarily possessed an eigenfunction of eigenvalue zero".

Could you help me in understanding this statement?

Edit:
the paper is [here](http://inspirehep.net/record/120130/).
In particular, he says that the equation
$$\frac{d^2x_n}{d {t}^2}+V''(\bar{x})x_n=\lambda_n x_n \tag{2.9}$$
must have a zero eigenvalue due to translational invariance of the theory. He then says which is this eigenfunction and I have checked that its eigenvalue is zero, after a brief computation. However, I still do not understand why expected this zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ref. 1 is interested in the limit where the characteristic duration of an instanton/bounce is much smaller than the full temporal integration region $[t_i,t_f]$, cf. the first column of p. 1764. (This is known as the dilute instanton gas model.) In other words, we can effectively consider an unbounded integration region $\mathbb{R}$ from $t_i=-\infty$ to $t_f=\infty$. This is time translation invariant, unlike its bounded counterparts.
2. Combined with the time translation invariance of the Lagrangian $L$, this implies that the instant of a instanton/bounce profile is arbitrary, i.e. the instanton/bounce has a moduli parameter along the time-axis, i.e. the classical path (satisfying the pertinent Dirichlet boundary conditions) is not unique, i.e. the [EL equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) has a zero-mode.
3. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219056/2451) related Phys.SE post, which deals with the very same Ref. 1.

References:

1. C.G. Callan, Jr. & S. Coleman, *Fate of the false vacuum. II. First quantum corrections,* [Phys. Rev. D 16 (1977) 1762](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.1762).